# How use a common 2,4 GHz wireless mouse with built in laptop bluetooth

Tags: windows-8.1, bluetooth, wireless-mouse, input-device

Why I can't use my wireless mouse with the built in laptop bluetooth and need a mouse receiver?

Comment: Because the receiver doesn't use Bluetooth but some proprietary protocol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "common 2.4GHz wireless mouse" is not Bluetooth.  Bluetooth may run on the same frequency, but it's completely different protocols.

Comment: Nope, not in the slightest.  If you want to use Bluetooth, you'll need to buy a Bluetooth mouse.

Comment: A microwave oven also runs at ~ 2.4 GHz...

Comment: can you give me a link? When I search on ebay or amazon for a bluetooth mouse I see only wireless mouse!

Comment: @toglun This link gives me lots of results: https://www.google.ca/search?q=bluetooth+mouse